# count everything charter in string

Tags: string, char

I'm sorry if this question is already asked on other threads but I just can't find my answer. I'm still a newbie at programming so please consider me :)

I need to create an application that lets the user enter a string and display the character that appears most frequently in the string.
1 Use a loop to select each character of the string
2 Inside the above loop, create a loop to compare the current character with each character in the a-z array
3 If a character matches, use the index to increment the current position in the integer array.
4 When the above loops have completed, loop through the integer array to find the highest count for a character

string = HELLLLOO
display = L

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. Does your teacher want pseudocode? What have you covered in class up to this point? Consider reviewing recent material for hints on how to do it.

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted so far?

Comment: I'm sorry guys if my question is unclear. I'm using C#. It is not an assignment though. It is just a weekly exercises and the numbered instructions is his tips for the exercise. I already attempted it but can't really figure it out.

Comment: I've already figured out the first part of the code. First, loop through the first character of the string, inside it another loop that compares the char with the first char in the a-z array. The part that confuses me is how to keep a count of every letter in the a-z array? And like what is mentioned above, how to use the index to increment the current position in the integer array and also in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there can be more efficient or easy way. I just write a simple solution through C# without test.

```
    string word = "HELLLOO";

    Dictionary<char, int> words = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++)
    {
       if(words.ContainsKey(word[i]))
       {
          words[word[i]] = words[word[i]] + 1;
       }
       else
          words.Add(word[i],1);
    }
    char maxWord;
    int maxVal = 0;
    foreach (var item in words)
    {
      if (item.Value > maxVal)
      {
        maxVal = item.Value;
        maxWord = item.Key;
      }
    }
```

you can display *maxWord* as the most used character of a word.

Comment: Thanks Gokhan! That helped. Although there are some words I'm not associated with. Like the "Dictionary" word? In that part, you're declaring a array right? And also I haven't encountered the word ContainsKey in our class. We're using Microsoft visual studio 2010 by the way.

Comment: as I've written I used C#, I don't know language that you are using. if you use .NET framework It'll work and you can convert it easily to visual basic or any other language that part of .net framework, or C/C++ you can reach the same results through making small changes and dictionary is like associative array and it is already implemented in the framework.

Comment: Buddy you've just saved my life. :)